# Sums of Convolutions vs Negative Sums of Convolutions

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, with probability density functions (pdfs) $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

Suppose we have a new random variable as the sum of these two variables $Z = X + Y$,

The convolution of $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ is defined as:

$$f_Z(z) = (f_X * f_Y)(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) dx$$

**My Question:**  Is it possibly to prove that sometimes that the convolution of $Z = X + Y$ is not the same $W = X - Y$?

Thanks!